# If I install IE9 (RC), will it migrate all the Favourites and Links I currently have in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, migration, internet-explorer-9

I'm really interested in moving to IE9 as my default browser, from IE8. But the only concern I have is that it will lose all my favourites and other bookmarks/links I have. I know that you cannot run IE8 and IE9 side-by-side, so when it uninstalls IE8, does migrate the settings and favourites to IE9?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would expect so - but being on XP I'm not able to test this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely all of your settings and favorites will be maintained when you install/upgrade any version of IE provided that your favorites were in IE to begin with and not in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Yup, just installed it and I was surprised it even remembered passwords and the order of my Favourites in the Favourites bar. Must say, it does seem faster. Not sure whether that's because it's new and different or because it is genuinely faster though!

Comment: IE9 has an entirely re-written display engine that uses your graphics card acceleration and a new JavaScript engine that should make JS-heavy sites like Facebook SCREAM. Compared to IE8, 9 is night-and-day faster.

Answer (score 1):

IE9 will call upon the same file folder as IE8 for its Favourites. In short, all of your favourites currently stored in IE8 will appear in the IE9 browser. I have migrated to IE9 as my default browser and there were no problems.